# Enter a variable into a command in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, input

My question should be simple for you guys.

I am writing a simple script that runs a command but the file it would need is always different.

Is there a way for it to ask:

"Where is the file?"

And then it adds it to the rest of the command and runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo Where is the file
read FILENAME

echo now reading ${FILENAME}
cat ${FILENAME}
$ ./foo.sh
Where is the file
/etc/fedora-release
now reading /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
$
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! It was my mistake. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As above but:

```
read -p "Where is the file?" FILENAME
```

Instead of echoing the question and then reading the variable, might be neater.